# Is it possible to have a back reference to a non-capturing group?

Tags: java, regex, backreference

I am tryint to create a regex/replacement pair to use with `replaceAll()` that will capture the characters just before and after a target string.

Here's my version, that works for simple cases:

```
String adjacent = "fooaXbcXdbar".replaceAll(".*?(.)X(.).*?(?=(.X)|$)", "$1$2");
```

which produces `"abcd"` as desired (the look ahead at the end is to consume to end of string making the single call to `replaceAll()` work).

However, there's an edge case I can't seem to solve for, when the character after the target is also a character before a target:

```
String adjacent = "fooaXbXdbar".replaceAll(".*?(.)X(.).*?(?=(.X)|$)", "$1$2");
```

produces `"ab"`, but I would like `"abbd"`. The regex has consumed the leading part of the match, making the following input not match.

I've tried look arounds, but can't seem to get it to work.

Note: I'm not interested in solutions that involve loops or code etc. Just seeking the regex and replacement string that will work for the edge case mentioned.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
String adjacent =
    "fooaXbXdbar".replaceAll(".*?(.)X(?:(?=(.)X)|(.).*?(?=.X|$))", "$1$2$3");
```

?

What it does is, after the `X`, it first checks to see if it's immediately followed by `.X`, in which case it captures the `.` as `$2` and considers the match complete; if it finds that it's *not* immediately followed by `.X`, it goes on to use the same logic that you were already using, capturing the subsequent character as `$3`.

(Note: I've tested this with both of your examples, but obviously it may miss other cases that you need to support. I recommend that you test it yourself as well.)

Comment: +1 It wasn't the "clean" answer I'd hoped for, but it's a great answer - cater for both simple and edge case in separate matches. Nice job!